# Question about definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So recently I was thinking about solving definite integrals forms of:
$$\int_{ka}^{kb} f(x) dx$$
and rearrange this as:
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(kx) dx$$
But it does not seem right when I actually calculate, I can't understand why... And if it is wrong is there any way to compress it?
And is there any name/topic for this type of compressing integrals? I would like to read about it!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are referring to [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) in integrals. You want to do the substitution $\tilde x = x/k$, this will give you the missing factor of $k$.

Comment: Hmm, but why do I have to multiply it by $k$?

Comment: Heuristically: You need to make up for the "compression", since you stretch/shrink it all by a factor $k$. I recommend any book about Calculus - the substitution will be explained there.

Comment: @DominikS Ohhh, it is because $\int f(kx) dx = \frac{1}{k}F(kx)$ right?
And then $\int_{ka}^{kb} f(x) dx = k\int_{a}^{b} f(kx) dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a *ton* of questions on this site about changing the limits of integration when invoking a change of variables / substitution.  See, for example, [change of variables for definite integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89718/) and [Why is it that, when using the u-substitution rule, you apply the the function u to the upper and lower limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3024683/) .  However, this particular problem has a nice geometric intuition and I can't find it already answered on the site, hence I think that it is worth answering separately, even if it is a kind of abstract duplicate.

#### Geometry

The basic intuition here comes from a result which is *usually* taught in precalculus classes in the US:

> **Theorem:**  Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and let $C > 0$.  Define a new function
> $$ g : [Ca, Cb] \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto f\left( \frac{1}{C} x \right). $$
> The graph of $g$ is identical to the graph of $f$ after a horizontal scaling by a factor of $C$.<sup>[1]</sup>

I am not going to prove this here, but it is something which is relatively easy to see and build some intuition for using a tool like [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/avbfb32s).  For example, in the following image, the function $f$ (in blue) is defined on the interval $[-1,3]$, while the function $g$ (in red) is a scaled copy of $f$, defined by the formula $g(x) = f(x/3)$.

[image]

If the integral is interpreted as the area under the curve, then this model makes it more clear that the area under $g$ is exactly $C$ times the area under $f$—horizontally scaling the graph of $f$ by a factor of $C$ scales the area by that same factor.  This implies that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = C \int_{Ca}^{Cb} f\left( \frac{1}{C} x\right) \,\mathrm{d}x. $$

#### Change of Variables

Note that this is the result which would be obtained via a more traditional change of variables or substitution:  to evaluate
$$\int_{ka}^{kb} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, $$
define $u = \frac{1}{k} x$.  Then $\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{k}\,\mathrm{d}x$, and
$$ x = ka \implies u = a
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
x = kb \implies u = b. $$
Therefore
$$ \int_{ka}^{kb} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{a}^{b} f(ku) \cdot k\,\mathrm{d}u
= k \int_{a}^{b} f(u) \,\mathrm{d}u. $$
This is exactly the same result as above, modulo renaming some of the variables and functions.

---

#### Notes

[1]  The result actually holds for a function defined on any domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and there are more general versions in higher dimensions, but I am choosing to state the theorem for intervals because the goal is to get to a definite integral.  Definite (Riemann) integrals are defined for functions on closed intervals, so the version of the theorem stated here is sufficient for the application here.